# React native fetch api render data in tableview

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I am fetching sample data from an API using the fetch in ComponentDidMount(). Once fetched, I want to display it in a tableview. But I'm getting an error in the simulator stating bundle error in the terminal:

> Failed to load bundle

Below is the code:

```
import React from 'react';

import { FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Text, View  } from 'react-native';

import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class FetchExample extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={ isLoading: true}
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson.movies,
        }, function(){

        });

      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      });
  }



  render(){

    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator/>
        </View>
      )
    }

    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop:20}}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <ListItem
           title={item.title} releaseYear={item.releaseYear}
           />
          )}
          keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full error.

Comment: Failed to load bundle.